# unhash password in view or controller in cakephp2 for edit

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I've encrypt password when user signup.
Now when user click to edit profile it shows encrypted password.
I want to know to How can i dencrypt the password in edit field?
Thanks.

Comment: Er, the point of hashing the password is that it's a one-way function.  Users would be (rightly) upset if you showed them that their passwords were not held securely.  Instead, allow them to enter (and confirm) a new password (probably backed by entering existing password); leave unchanged if no new password is provided.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, this is a **security feature**.

> You should never store plain text passwords, and before saving a user record you should always hash the password.
>
> http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#hashing-passwords

The only thing that can be done is verify if a given password matches the previous one, see [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

```
<?php
// To update the password, we need the old password
// as well as a new one.
if (password_verify($old_password, $hash)) {
    $hash = password_hash($new_password);
}
```